# useSelector is defined after dispatching but then undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to get initial data from a reducer by dispatching action from App.js component, it works fine but when I switch to another component and load it with useSelector it gets undefined.
I have tried this line of code in Headphones.js but the second one returns undefined

```
const allData = useSelector((state) => state.allDataReducer);
const { loading, error, data } = allData;
```

App.js

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(welcomeAction());
    dispatch(listAllData);
  }, [dispatch]);
```

allDataReducer.js

```js
import {
  LIST_ALL_DATA_FAIL,
  LIST_ALL_DATA_REQUEST,
  LIST_ALL_DATA_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/shared";

export const allDataReducer = (state = { loading: true, data: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
case LIST_ALL_DATA_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true };
case LIST_ALL_DATA_SUCCESS:
  return { loading: false, data: action.payload };
case LIST_ALL_DATA_FAIL:
  return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
default:
  return state;
  }
};
```

shared.js

```js
import {
  LIST_ALL_DATA_FAIL,
  LIST_ALL_DATA_REQUEST,
  LIST_ALL_DATA_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/shared";
import Axios from "axios";

export const listAllData = async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LIST_ALL_DATA_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get("/all");
    dispatch({ type: LIST_ALL_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LIST_ALL_DATA_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

Headphones.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listheadphones } from "../actions/headphonesActions";
import BasicSection from "../components/BasicSection";
import Definer from "../components/Definer";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import ProductsCategories from "../components/ProductsCategories";
import BestAudioGear from "../components/BestAudioGear";

const Headphones = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const headphonesList = useSelector((state) => state.headphonesList);

  const allData = useSelector((state) => state.allData);
        const { loading, error, data } = allData; //undefined
  //const { loading, error, headphones } = headphonesList;
  console.log(headphonesList);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listheadphones());
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Definer title="HEADPHONES" />
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        headphones.map((headphone) => (
          <BasicSection
            key={headphone.id}
            name={headphone.headerName}
            info={headphone.info}
            mobile={headphone.mobile}
            tablet={headphone.tablet}
            desktop={headphone.desktop}
          />
        ))
      )}
      <ProductsCategories />
      <BestAudioGear />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Headphones;
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/elabdelaziz/Audiophile-Ecom)

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How are you using it in the other component? Add the code from that file too.

Comment: Also a link is better not to add. If there is anything behind the link, simply add it here as code, an image, or text.

Comment: i have added code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Your description is still not specific enough, can't really pin down what the issue is. But here is some stuff I noticed:

`dispatch(listAllData);` somehow looks wrong to me, the action creator is usually a function that gets called: `dispatch(listAllData());`

Then where you define `export const listAllData = async (dispatch) => {` - this should be a function that returns a function if you're using the thunk middleware. You only defined a function.